# Various questions about io.sockets.manager and join functions of Socket.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have some questions regarding Socket.io and could not find any answer for following terms/functions/whatever of Socket.io. These are used in hundreds of examples to create chat system but none of them has clearly defined what these terms do.

1. what does `io.sockets.manager` do?
2. what does `io.sockets.join()` do?
3. can client.leave() be used to to leave some joint room? or what?

And another question is that if I have created Rooms array which holds ids of different rooms. Now how can I send message to only particular room? Suppose

```
var Rooms = [ 
   { 'a' : 'Room1' }, 
   { 'b' : 'Room2' }, 
   { 'c' : 'Room3' }
]
```

How can I send message to `Rooms['a']` only? Like to send `msg` to all, it's just:

```
io.sockets.emit('server_says', { msg: 'Hello All'});
```

Where can I find some article where all such functions like `join()`, `manager` etc are found with their details?

Please if possible provide some code so I can understand better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have not done your homework. You can find everything about Socket.io at

https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

https://medium.com/@noufel.gouirhate/build-a-simple-chat-app-with-node-js-and-socket-io-ea716c093088

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/socket.io/socket.io_chat_application.htm

https://itnext.io/building-a-node-js-websocket-chat-app-with-socket-io-and-react-473a0686d1e1

These links include answers to all your questions.

Comment: those links are dead

Comment: Dead links, please consider updating this answer